# How Do Find Word Fragment In Visual Basic

Tags: vba, fragment, whitespace

How do I find a partial word in a Visual Basic macro in Microsoft Word? I want to find all occurrences of the word fragment but not the whole word. In other words, I want strings that (1) do not have spaces before them and (2) only have spaces or punctuation after them.

E.g. A search for "able," would return dependable but not able or abley.

I want to find and highlight all occurrences: either highlight the word fragment only or highlight the whole word containing the word fragment.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that from you. If the post helps you, you can mark it as answer and close the post.

Comment: That means you can pass the word you want to find as a parameter to the RegExp.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your case, I have created a simple Regular Expression to find related words. Please try the code as below:

```
Sub RegSearchHL()
Dim myMatches, myMatch
Dim regExp As Object
Set regExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With regExp
   .Pattern = "[A-Za-z]+able+[\ \.\,\:\?\!\;]"   'please replace your text
   .Global = True
End With
Set myMatches = regExp.Execute(ActiveDocument.Content.Text)
For Each match In myMatches
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = match.Value
    .Replacement.Text = match.Value
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll    
Next match
End Sub
```

Also, you could pass your parameter to RegExp Pattern and update your needed.

Thanks,

Yuki

Comment: Hi. What do you mean that I could pass my parameter to RegExp Pattern and update?  Thanks.

Comment: That means you can pass the word you want to find as a parameter to the RegExp.